# IPad Air won't play any videos now

Tags: ipad, video, ios

My iPad now won't play any videos from any site. Netflix, Safari, the YouTube app, YouTube within Safari, iMovie, and Pinnacle Studio Pro all cannot play videos after the update.

My software is up to date with the latest update, I just checked it today.

I've cleared my network settings, cookies, history, rebooted the iPad and tried five different networks.

I don't know what else to try. It's been like this for four weeks now.

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1):

First make a backup using iTunes or iCloud. As Apple Support suggest their first solution would be do a Network settings reset. I think that what you said you have done already . If you have already done that, they said to reset all settings. That would probably solve your problem. If that ain't help either just do a Erase all content and settings reset. If neither of them work properly, you have to take that into Apple support center.  Before do any of these reset, I highly recommend to backup device.